# Keycloak login page reload issue. /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html 404 error

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

Keycloak login page is reloading continuously automatically. After inspecting networking tab, I came to know that an html page(**/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html**) is giving **404** in response.

I am running **quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0** keycloak image.

I am providing the following variables in environment(also providing database vars.)

- name: KC_HOSTNAME

  value: my-domain
- name: KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH

  value: "/auth"
- name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING

  value: "True"
- name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED

  value: "True"

Which configuration am I missing in environment variables?

Comment: Is there a version query parameter present on that request?

Comment: Issue is resolved. I was providing wrong frontend url.